# Multi delete, unknown table error when one table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I delete from two tables with primary entry.

- Both tables use to store image id.
- One for display image and other is to save in favourite.
- When both tables has entry, multi delete query works fine.

**But:**

- When favourite table is empty, query doesn’t work for one table and show error as favourite is unknown table.
- Do you have any experiences multi delete from two tables (when one is empty)?

I tried in various ways but same errors:

```php
$sql = "DELETE FROM stat, s_images, favourites USING stat, s_images,
        favourites WHERE favourites.image=stat.id AND stat.id=s_images.id AND
        stat.id=" . $this->id;

$sql = "DELETE stat, s_images,favourites FROM stat, s_images,
        favourites WHERE favourites.image=stat.id AND stat.id=s_images.id AND
        stat.id=" . $this->id;
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Have a look at how to write a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited question, could you please check ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an explicit inner join

```
DELETE stat, s_images, favourites
FROM stat
INNER JOIN s_images
ON s_images.id = stat.id
INNER JOIN favourites
ON favourites.image = stat.id
WHERE stat.id = $this->id;
```

This will cause nothing to be deleted when a match is not found in any of the joins.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/580be/2

Otherwise you may need to perform individual queries or utilize [Foreign Key Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to Cascade on delete.

You could also ignore the errors, but this is bad practice.

```
DELETE IGNORE stat, s_images, favourites
FROM stat
LEFT JOIN s_images
ON s_images.id = stat.id
LEFT JOIN favourites
ON favourites.image = stat.id
WHERE stat.id = $this->id;
```

---

**UPDATE with Foreign Keys**

Add constraint for `s_images.id` + `stat.id`

```
ALTER TABLE `stat`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_stat_s_images` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `s_images` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Add constraint for `s_images.id` + `favourites.image`

```
ALTER TABLE `favourites`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_favourites_s_images` FOREIGN KEY (`image`) REFERENCES `s_images` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then all you need to do is execute the query to delete the images, MySQL will ensure your records are managed appropriately, and will aid in optimizations.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM s_images
WHERE s_images.id = '" . $this->id . "'";
```

---

**Special Considerations**

1. Tables must use the InnoDB engine as foreign keys do not work with MyISAM.

```
ALTER TABLE `stat` ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `favourites` ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `s_images` ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

2. INSERT and UPDATE must use proper ordering, meaning you can not create an association on `favourites.image = 1` when the record for `s_images.id = 1` does not exist. The record `s_images.id = 1` would need to be created prior to the `favourites` record.
3. You will not be able to add the FOREIGN KEY constraints when an id is referenced that does not exist. You can override this behavior by using

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
 ALTER TABLE `stat`
        ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_stat_s_images` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `s_images` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

4. In order to prevent deletion of records, for historical reference purposes, you can set the constraint to set NULL instead of cascade.

```
ALTER TABLE `favourites`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_favourites_s_images` FOREIGN KEY (`image`) REFERENCES `s_images` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: I tried both of your ways as well, It doesn't work..@fyrye

Comment: @user3541740 `DELETE IGNORE` should have worked, what error message was given? I suggest setting up a `FOREIGN KEY` to cascade on delete. I updated my answer to help you accomplish doing so.